# .NET GridView rows is null on postback

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gridview, viewstate

I'm having difficulty in iterating over a GridView's rows once it has been populated after a postback.

In summary, there are two dropdown lists which determine the data that should be displayed within the GridView. The page is initially loaded with just the two dropdown lists, no GridView at this stage. After values have been selected from the dropdowns, user submits the page via a button. The code behind then makes a call to the db to retrieve the data and bind this to the GridView. I've managed to get this working!

The problem is that the GridView has one column where the user can edit the values within a textbox held in an itemtemplate. If the users changes the values in the textbox and submits the page, when I try to iterate over the GridView's rows, it's telling me there are no rows to iterate over. I'm confused as to why this is happening when I can see rows and data available in the front-end.

However, if we remove the step which involves the user selecting the dropdowns and the GridView is populated on initial page_load, I can actually iterate over the rows.

So it's as if the ViewState is not persisting the number of rows between the postbacks if a GridView is bound within an button click event.

Could someone explain to me, what's going on.

Here's the code in VB.NET:

```
Protected Sub Me_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub BtnGetData_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles BtnGetData.Click

    Dim ddlFirstValue As Integer = DropDownListOne.SelectedValue
    Dim ddlSecondValue As Integer = DropDownListSecond.SelectedValue
    MyGridView.DataSource = GetData(ddlFirstValue, ddlSecondValue)
    MyGridView.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub BtnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles BtnSubmit.Click

    For Each row As GridViewRow In MyGridView.Rows 'this returning 0 rows
        'Do something
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are asking.  So you click a button to populate your gridview and then click another to submit any changes to it?  But when you submit it there are no rows?

Comment: Yes, that's right there are no rows. When I try to iterate over the GridView.Rows it's saying 0 rows are being returned.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* we may need more data to describe why the behavior is happening in your particular case.  For example, you *might* consider posting your ASPX (XHTML) file so we can get a better look at your exact situation.

While I *may* not fully understand your needs, it *seems* that what you want is possible.  Below is a contrived example I put together to loosely simulate *my* understanding of your situation.

The code I am submitting allows the user to:

1. Open a Page with an Empty GridView
2. Select from a DropDown a Weight Filter (No Postback Yet)
3. Select from another DropDown a Cost Filter (No Postback Yet)
4. Push a Get Data Button to Populate the GridView
5. Type information in TextBoxes for the Description field on each GridView Row
6. Click the Submit Button
7. Observe the user's choices via Server Side modifications to a literal control

Since the processing occurs on the server, I think this code demonstrates that it should be possible to modify a GridView in the precribed manner and read the GridView changes.

If this code does not describe your situation, please add comments so the community can provide you with better assistance:

**ASPX Simulation File**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" 
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>
    Demo of using DropDown Lists to Filter Data for 
    Editable DataGrid
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Literal ID="theLiteral" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        DataKeyNames="weight, cost, Description">
            <Columns>               
                <asp:BoundField DataField="weight" HeaderText="Weight" /> 
                <asp:BoundField DataField="cost" HeaderText="Cost" /> 
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="descId"
                        Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />                          
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView><br />
        Get Items With Weight >=:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListOne" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />            
            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" />      
            <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />                  
        </asp:DropDownList><br />
        Get Items With Cost >=:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSecond" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />            
            <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />      
            <asp:ListItem Text="51" Value="51" />    
            <asp:ListItem Text="101" Value="101" />                                
        </asp:DropDownList><br />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnGetData" runat="server" Text="Get Data" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" /><br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind Simulation File**

```
' Just some DataItem to stick in an IEnumerable Array to be 
' bound to CreativeInCode's MyGridView
public Class InventoryItem
    Public Sub New (
        ByVal iWeight As Integer, 
        ByVal iCost As Integer, 
        ByVal iDescription As String) 

        weight = iWeight
        cost = iCost
        description = iDescription
    End Sub

    ' Automatic VB.NET properties can be read about here:
    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx
    Public Property weight As Integer
    Public Property cost As Integer
    Public Property description As String
End Class

' The code behind for Default.aspx starts here
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    ' Data to play with 
    Public storeItems As InventoryItem() = 
    {
        New InventoryItem(10, 20, "PaperWeight"), 
        New InventoryItem(1, 1, "Feather"), 
        New InventoryItem(2000, 20000, "Used SUV"), 
        New InventoryItem(3, 50, "Biology TextBook"), 
        New InventoryItem(1, 200, "Professional Isolation Headphones"), 
        New InventoryItem(1, 100, "Caviar (Does this Need to Be Refrigerated?)")
    }

    ' Function to simulate retrieval from DataBase
    Protected Function GetData( _ 
        ByVal weight As Integer, 
        ByVal cost As INteger
    ) As IEnumerable(Of InventoryItem)
        ' Example of LINQ can be found here
        ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088.aspx
        ' I believe LINQ is the way of the future
        Dim returnValue As IEnumerable(Of InventoryItem) = 
            From items In storeItems
            Where (items.weight >= weight) AndAlso (items.cost >= cost)
            Select items
        Return returnValue
    End Function

     ' CreativeInCode's STuff starts here
    Protected Sub Me_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _ 
        Handles Me.Load 

    End Sub 

    Protected Sub BtnGetData_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _ 
        Handles BtnGetData.Click 

        Dim ddlFirstValue As Integer = DropDownListOne.SelectedValue 
        Dim ddlSecondValue As Integer = DropDownListSecond.SelectedValue                 
        MyGridView.DataSource = GetData(ddlFirstValue, ddlSecondValue) 
        myGridView.DataBind()

    End Sub 

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Made some modifications to CreativeInCode's function to 
    ''' dump the output to the user
    ''' </summary>                
    Protected Sub BtnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _ 
        Handles BtnSubmit.Click 

        Dim outputToUser As String = _
            "The user put the following values in the GridView:<br />" 
        For Each row As GridViewRow In MyGridView.Rows 'this returning 0 rows 
            'Do something 

            ' This is just here to make a good place to set a 
            ' breakpoint            
            Dim weightStr As String = row.Cells(0).Text
            Dim costStr As String = row.Cells(1).Text
            Dim tbDescription As TextBox = row.FindControl("descId")
            Dim description As String = tbDescription.Text

            outputToUser &= 
                String.Format(
                    "weight={0}, cost={1}, description={2}<br />", _
                    weightStr, _ 
                    costStr, _
                    description
                )           
        Next 

        ' Show the user the changes she/he made to the GridView
        theLiteral.Text = outputToUser
    End Sub 
End Class
```